# How to run a Morbo Server of Mojolicious from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl, eclipse-plugin, mojolicious, morbo

I am very new to perl. I was trying to import a perl project in Eclipse & run it. I am able to import it. The application runs by using this command:
`morbo script/better_ed -l http://*:3010`

I came to know that it runs a morbo server. How to run this server inside Eclipse so that I can debug. I have installed Epic & PadWalker

Comment: Do you want Eclipse to start the morbo, or do you just want to attach to the process for debugging?

Comment: @simbabque I want to attach the process for debugging. But I believe for that I need to start the server in Eclipse. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am not sure. I think you do not. Morbo is Perl under the hood, and you should be able to attach to it with Perl's debugging stuff the same way that you can do to any other Perl process. It shouldn't be that different from doing remote CGI debugging. I don't know how to do that with Eclipse, but I've done it in the past using Komodo IDE. You might want to look for tutorials on debugging Dancer or Catalyst, if you cannot find anything Mojo-specific. They should all be the same thing really.